# What are the size limits of file *.agg.flex.data?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, aggregation, olap, olap-cube

What are the size limits of file *.agg.flex.data ?These files are typically located at SSAS data directory.

While processing the cubes with "Process Index", I am getting below error message:

> File system error: The following file is corrupted: Physical file: \?\F:\OLAP\.0.db\.0.cub\.0.det\.0.prt\33.agg.flex.data. Logical file .

However, if we navigate to the location mentioned in the error message, the specified file is not present(at given location).

If anyone have faced such issue earlier please help.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have checked the different agg.flex.data file sizes, these file sizes were varying from ~200MB to ~5GB. Is there any size limit configuration associated with these files?If yes, can we change it in SQL Server 2008 R2. Else any Update which takes care of such configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe agg.flex.data files have a hard upper limit. I suspect that error either means you had a disk failure or that the database is corrupt. I would either unprocess (ProcessClear) and reprocess the database. Or I would delete the database and redeploy and process. Hopefully you can workaround that error.

Comment: In my case thes files are randomly getting deleted, and still facing such error messages. However, I don't have any fact source/fact tables present to reprocess the entire OLAP database. I have also checked, there are no disk failure or Database corruption.

Comment: Oh dear. You may be in trouble. Maybe you could disassociate the partitions from the aggregation design and run ProcessIndexes to see if it will delete all the agg files.

Comment: Also I would open a support case to resolve the bug. But just be warned it is never recommended to delete your SQL fact table since you may need to reprocess your cube at some point.

Comment: If i disassociate the partitions from aggregation design, I fear if they will be processed correctly again while process indexes. Also, could you please let me know the support case number for this issue?
I have noticed another strange thing that, whenever these(*.agg.flex.data) files grow larger than 4-5GBs, SQL Server seems to be deleting these files. And once these files are deleted I am facing the same error message again.

Comment: You are saying this is a recurring problem? I misunderstood. I thought it was a one time oddity you wanted to temporarily work around. In that case make sure you are on the latest service pack and cumulative update. What version are you on? Drop and redeploy your database. Then if it happens again open a support case. Incidentally I remembered incorrectly. There has been a lot of churn around indexes of agg files, but that is a different file extension. I don't have a support case number.

Comment: Did you see this similar thread? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b7e9d8cc-270e-4cec-8d86-ee37a524fbe6/a-map-files-gets-corrupted-from-time-to-time?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Comment: I have seen the link, but its not helpful. However, I have opened the similar thread on MSDN, [LINK](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9bab5ed9-4e55-4a47-8601-d6c837e432a3/what-are-the-size-limits-of-file-aggflexdata?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

Comment: Hi All, is there anything else which I can do? Since the agg.flex.data files are again growing(after re- deploying the new Cube database) quite quickly. I fear this may again lead to **File system error: The following file is corrupted: Physical file: \?\F:\OLAP\.0.db\.0.cub\.0.det\.0.prt\33.agg.flex.data. Logical file** error. Can someone please let me know any way around?

Comment: Open a support case. It's a bug